# The donor energy for a doped semiconductor with anisotropic dispersion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Modelling the impurity as a hydrogenic system in a uniform dielectric of permittivity $\varepsilon$, the donor ionization energy is given by a modification to Bohr's result for the hydrogen atom:

$$E_d=\frac{e^4m^*}{32(\pi\varepsilon\hbar)^2}$$
Here $m^*$ is the effective mass of the donor electron.

If we interpret this as the minimum energy required to strip the donor electron off of the donor to become conduction electron, then in the band diagram the donor energy level would be located $E_d$ below the conduction band minimum $E_c$.

For an anisotropic dispersion relation for the conduction band of the semiconductor, say

$$E(k)=\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\left[\frac{k_{et}^2}{m_{et}}+\frac{k_{el}^2}{m_{el}}\right]$$

where the subscripts denote the transversal and longitudinal directions, **how do I express $m^*$?**

Since for anisotropic dispersion the effective mass is in the form of a tensor, I figure that the donor energy should depend on the direction, too, i.e. I should use $m_{et}$ for the transversal direction and $m_{el}$ for the longitudinal direction.

Is this the correct interpretation, or might it be the case that the Bohr model does not apply in such cases?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the thing they would do, as is the usual lazy thing we almost always do in physics, is to find a value of $m^*$ that would fit the correct $E_d$ and call it a day. I mean, you are already learning semiconductors, the authors will assume that you know that comparing with Bohr model is but a shorthand for memorising a roughly correct behaviour. So they will be incredibly sloppy. Especially since the real physics is so much more complicated and we frequently have difficulty predicting the real $E_d$ and instead just obtain it very crudely from experiment.